# Gas line in contact with concrete - is this code compliant?

Tags: code-compliance, natural-gas

I'm approaching the end of my initial builder warranty on my home and had a home inspection service come out and identify potential problems. One of the items identified is the natural gas line in this photo which serves an outdoor BBQ area. The gas line is inside the constructed cabinet for the BBQ.

The inspector identified that the gas line should not be in contact with the concrete and that the "duct" tape is not adequate. I assume the city building inspector would have noticed this if it was not to code but one can never be sure about such things. It's also possible the sub-contractor filled the concrete base after the gas line was inspected.

EDIT to respond to comment in an answer: It appears to be a carbon steel line but I don't know for sure. The area is protected from weather because it is in a cabinet built for a BBQ though I'm sure it could get wet under specific storm conditions.

[image]

I'm in Scottsdale, AZ and the home was completed in late 2019 and occupied in March, 2020.

I will report this to the builder as a warranty issue but wanted to know if this is or is not code compliant? Reference to the code either way would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: add additional photos of structure housing the gas line. The line is just inside and to the right of the access door:

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The pipe may be coated “black iron” this is what is required below grade in my jurisdiction. Code doesn't identify the method. I usually use tape as my threader takes off about 3”.

Answer (score 1):

The only code I know around gas lines pertains to foundation walls/floor.   There it must be in a sleeve.   For this, it is certainly best practice (and actually easier to pour concrete with a sleeve).

This is really only an issue in your case if the gas line material is corrosive to water and may never be an issue at all if it is under something and never sees standing water.   What material is used for your lines?

Comment: Based on what I see in the rest of the house, I believe it's carbon steel. I don't know for sure.

Comment: Carbon steel will rust...   I am not sure this would be covered by warranty but you can take it to them and act like it should.    I would call the city inspector and ask them if it meets local code.

Comment: I've added additional photos to show the "cabinet" within which the gas line is found.

Comment: I like copper for gas pits and outdoor stuff.    I will say this though... I am not sure how much longer a gas line will last with duct tape vs a sleeve.   I doubt there is a substantial difference when your line is in a cabinet.   The most corrosion will not from moisture in air or under the concrete.

Comment: A large caution for copper is ammonia. If ammonia or amine cleaners could get splashed on it they will cause corrosion. The extent of corrosion will depend on the specific  exposure.